# virt-manager: Group 14 is not suitable

Tags: virtualization, virt-manager, virsh

I followed this tutorial (here: https://passthroughpo.st/new-and-improved-mac-os-tutorial-part-1-the-basics/) but when I pass through my GPU, it errors out with something along the lines of Group 14 is not suitable and QEMU closed the monitor. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Update:
I tried passing through the audio card, as per a suggestion from a friend. But then when I run the VM (via the play button), nothing happens. `virt-manager` still says it's not running...

Update 2:
When I tried removing the GPU and adding just the audio card, the VM hangs. This doesn't happen with the GPU...

Note: I don't have the full error right now, but I'll edit this and post it later.

Comment: When you update with error message, please also add some HW info like GPU and CPU. Maybe you can also shareoutput of  `lspci -nnk`?

Comment: @akane I'll do that. Is there any way I can check if an AUR package is safe? It might be because the `linux-vfio` kernel patch isn't installed, but it's an AUR package...

Comment: @akane, I edited my post with some more information...